# Does Dual Nature mean that any wave will have a particle counterpart?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

Does Dual Nature mean that any wave will have a particle counterpart? electrons have electron waves and light waves are made up of photons. Does this mean all kinds of waves have its particle counterpart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Dual Nature of Matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56103/)

Comment: From Wiki: Wave–particle duality is the concept in quantum mechanics that every particle or quantum entity may be partly described in terms not only of particles, but also of waves.

Answer (score 0):

No. Electrons are both *particles and wave* at the same time. As much as it is true that light is a *wave* during diffraction, and seems like a *particle* while doing the photoelectric effect.

This is not the same as having counterparts.